# AndroidStudio compile c++ met a problem like this:<mmintrin.h> __builtin_ia32_emms();

Tags: c++, android-studio, shared-libraries

when I was trying to compile a c++ code to be a so library using android studio. I met a problem like this:

```
<mmintrin.h> use of undeclared identifier:  __builtin_ia32_emms();
```

who can help me?

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217812/c-compilation-issue-with-emmintrin-h-on-linux-gcc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NDK build opencv error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192752/ndk-build-opencv-error)

Answer (score 0):

emmintrin.h is for x86 architecture not for arm

Either limit the ndk abiFilters to 'x86' or change the emmintrin.h file with the one for arm

Check this github for arm version :
https://github.com/jratcliff63367/sse2neon